# error convertion from 'DataBaseEntities' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2015, objectcontext

I am trying to develop a Sales and Inventory system using VS2015 c#.
However, today I am getting errors. Here's my code:

```
 public partial class Form4 : Form
{

    private BindingList<tblProduct> products = new BindingList<tblProduct>();

    private db_22VapeStreetEntities cse = new db_22VapeStreetEntities();

    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lstProductsChosen.DataSource = products;
        lstProductsChosen.DisplayMember = "Description";

        createTabbedPanel();

    }

    private void AddProductsToTabbedPannel()
    {
        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            ObjectQuery<tblProduct> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<tblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P", cse);

        }
```

The error is when I call the "cse" here --> `ObjectQuery<tblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P", cse);`
I am getting

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'inventorysystem.db_22VapeStreetEntities' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'

I tried searching the problem but I can't see any solutions.

Comment: what is the base type of `db_22VapeStreetEntities`?

Comment: Sorry I don't really know.

Comment: Put the cursor on `db_22VapeStreetEntities` and press `F12` and see what that type is.

Comment: public partial class db_22VapeStreetEntities : DbContext
    {
        public db_22VapeStreetEntities()
            : base("name=db_22VapeStreetEntities")
        {
        }

Comment: Just do this: `var products = cse.tblProduct.Select()` but I cannot see your entity model code so if that does not work then try putting an `s` at the end of `tblProduct`.

Comment: Where should I put the code? Inside the "base("name=db_22VapeStreetEntities") { }"?

Comment: Put that in `AddProductsToTabbedPannel` instead of the query that is causing the error. If you need to filter based on some value then do this: `var products = cse.tblProduct.Where(x => x.WhateverColumn == "whatevervalue").ToList();` where `WhateverColumn` is the name of the column you want to filter by and `whatevervalue` is the value. I need to go to sleep now. good luck

Answer (score 1):

From the little code you have posted, it is possible your entity context is actually a DBContext.

If that is the case, then try this

```
    foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        ObjectQuery<tblProduct> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<tblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P", ((IObjectContextAdapter)cse).ObjectContext);
    }
```

> If this helps though you should investigate newer ways to parameterize your queries with conditional filters using DBContext. I presume for now you have other reasons for staying with ObjectContext patterns.

If you have a DBContext, try this Linq statement:

```
IQueryable<tblProduct> filteredProduct = cse.tblProducts.AsQueryable();
```

Or as you have omitted the actual filter syntax that you are using we can try something like this:

```
string filterValue = "value1";
IQueryable<tblProduct> filteredProduct = cse.tblProducts.Where(p => p.FilterColumn == filterValue);
```

Comment: Should I be using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure for that? or generate interface?

Comment: I'm going to say yes... There are specific use cases for ObjectQuery, they are generally restricted to when your UI controls want to generate the the query or filter statements dynamically at runtime. I'll edit the answer to show an alternate syntaxt. Again, I am still assuming a lot about your code base.

Comment: I used 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;' and error occurs: _Interface implemented by objects that can provide an IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext instance. The System.Data.Entity.DbContext class implements this interface to provide access to the underlying ObjectContext.  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' _

Comment: Right I see. I am using EF6 via nuget: PM> Install-Package EntityFramework   It sounds like you might just be using EF direct from System.Data.Entity... Things have evolved a lot since then. Again consider not using ObjectQuery